# Is there a way to access the value property of an item within a nodeList?

Tags: javascript

I have created a nodeList of all the rows in my document. When I created these rows using JS I assigned values to the rows. Now I would like to access these values.

I've tried the following but no success:

```
const allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var x = allRows[i].value;
```

and

```
const allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var x = allRows[i].nodeValue;
```

I've read that if the node is an element node, the nodeValue property will return null.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns an [`HTMLcollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) not a `NodeList`

Comment: Only <input>s and <select>s have a `.value`. How did you assign the value to the rows? I'd use `.dataset`, which allows to assign arbitrary values to elements.

Comment: _“When I created these rows using JS I assigned values to the rows.”_ - meaning what, exactly? Please do not give us such vague verbal descriptions of what you did, but provide proper [mre]s of your issues.

Answer (score 1):

`tr` elements don't have a `value` property (or attribute), and the [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) property (inherited from the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface) is always `null` for [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)s and their subclasses (including [`HTMLTableRowElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement), which is what a `tr` is).

If you've put a `value` attribute on a `tr` element, it's invalid; use `data-value` or similar instead, and access it through [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) or `getAttribute` ([more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)).

Or if you're trying to access the cells (`td` and `th` elements) in the `tr` using `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` on it, or via its `cells` property (that latter one is standard, but not generally recommended). They, too, don't have `value` or a meaningful `nodeValue`, but they have `textContent` and `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I assumed I could add a value to a row... my mistake. My idea was to create rows and label them with one of several values so that I could filter the rows via a drop down list. So is the only way to select a specific set of rows by their text content or innerHTML?

Comment: @mich-ish - I think a `data-` attribute would probably suit what you're describing (see the [more here link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) in the answer for details). CSS doesn't have a selector based on the text in an element, but does have attribute selectors.